# How do I read the US Presidential Election Results as shown by Google?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

When Googling `Presidential Election Results` the following metadata is shown, part of which is confusing me. Can anyone enlighten me as to what these percentages represent? (Obviously the other numbers represent number of votes)

[image]

Comment: Looks like a browser issue (or maybe an issue on Google's end that they've since fixed) -- for me, that page has those numbers in the right column and the candidates' info on the left, and it's titled "Popular vote".

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks, looks to be an issue with my browser. Doh!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the popular vote percentage for the respective candidate.